# function inside an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

What I'm trying to accomplish is calling `result.MappingWaypoints[i].lat();` and 
`result.MappingWaypoints[i].lng();` instead of `result.MappingWaypoints[i].lat;` and `result.MappingWaypoints[i].lng`.

Is this even possible?

```
var result = new Array();
    result = {
        'MappingWaypoints': MappingWaypoints,
        'Flightime': flight_time_sec,
        'PhotoArea': {  'SouthWest': MeterstoGPS(starting_photo_area),
                        'NorthEast': MeterstoGPS(end_photo_area)},
    };


 MappingWaypoints.push(
 {
    lat : current_point_gps.lat,
    lng : current_point_gps.lng,
    Radius : 10,
    Altitude : Attitude,
    ClimbRate : ClimbRate,
    DelayTime : DelayTime,
    WP_Event_Channel_Value : 100,
    Heading : 0,
    Speed : Speed,
    CAM_Nick : 0,
    Type : 1,
    Prefix : "P"
 }
```

Edit: I tried adding :

```
lat: function(){ return current_point_gps.lat},`


lng : function(){ return current_point_gps.lng},
```

But that doesn't work => all values of the array have the lat/long value of the first coord

edit2: Thanks to @DCoder for this answer in the comments below: this solved it for me.

```
lat: (function(v) { return function() { return v; } })(current_point_gps.lat)
```

I know this might seem to be a strange thing to do but an algorithm i'm using really needs to acces data as a function call because the algo also processes data from the google api where data is only accessible trough the same function call lat() and lng(). THANKS :)

Comment: Unless you create a more complex solution for storage, the answers given so far will blow up once the value of `current_point_gps` changes.

Comment: Side note - you're mixing up arrays and objects (which are associative arrays) so don't use `var result = new array()` when you're treating it as an associative array/object.

Comment: @DCoder: you're absoltely right

Comment: Try this instead: `lat: (function(v) { return function() { return v; } })(current_point_gps.lat)`.

Comment: @PhonicUK: yes result shouldn't be an array but this doesn't solve my problem I think

Comment: Assuming you put the exact code above in, your inline functions are missing their semicolons after the return.

Comment: @DCoder: excellent that works: thanks; Can you add an answer than I can mark it as the right one. Thanks again.

Comment: @PhonicUK; these are just code taken from a large program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original approach runs into the problem that is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) - due to JS variable scope, all the functions will point to (and return) the same variable.

You need to capture the *value* you want to return for each property, instead of capturing a *variable*. The simplest way to do that is a self-executing function:

```
{
  lat: (function(v) { return function() { return v; } })(current_point_gps.lat),
  lng: (function(v) { return function() { return v; } })(current_point_gps.lng),
  ....
}
```

---

If you need a way to also edit the `lat` property, then you can either add a public property to the object, like this:

```
{
  lat: function() { return this._lat; },
  _lat: current_point_gps.lat
}
```

Or you can use something similar to jQuery's "0 arguments means get, 1 argument means set" paradigm and use this:

```
{
  lat: (function(v) { return function() { 
    if(arguments.length) {
      v = arguments[0];
    } else { 
      return v; 
    };
  })(current_point_gps.lat)
}

obj.lat(); // returns the current value
obj.lat(55); // changes the current value to 55, returns nothing
obj.lat(); // returns 55
```

Comment: Is it also possible to change this value of lat and lng with or without function once the array is created? (edit: not pushing; i want to change the value of lat/lng because their coord are rotated)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call them as a function.

```
lat : function(){ return current_point_gps.lat },
lng : function(){ return current_point_gps.lng },
```

That should work (not tested ;) ).

But why would you wan't to do that?

Edit:

If you want to pass the function, you should not call the function.

```
// Pass the Result of a function, the function is called
var foobar = result.MappingWaypoints[i].lng();

// Pass the function itself, the function wont be called
var foobar = result.MappingWaypoints[i].lng;
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that. I know this seems strange but the reason is that another method absolutely need to access the data as a function...

Comment: Then try this and remove the ();

Comment: That way the variables become functions. But using lat(); you will pass the result of the function, and that would be a string. Pass lat and then you will pass the function itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what do you mean by try this and remove the (); the () after function?

Answer (score 0):

```
lat : function() { return current_point_gps.lat },
lng : function() { return current_point_gps.lng },
```

i don't see why this is necessary though

Comment: should have mentioned that I tried that. I know this seems strange but the reason is that another method absolutely need to access the data as a function..